# What should I supply to the "freq" input for Frequency Xlating FIR Filter for GnuRadio Companion?

Tags: filtering, gnuradio, software-defined-radio

I am using GnuRadio Companion (GRC) 3.75 and I am trying to use the Frequency Xlating FIR Filter (FXFF) block to perform some filtering.

All the tutorials I've seen had this FXFF block take in only 1 input (such as [this](https://tapiovalli.wordpress.com/2014/08/02/rtl-sdr-gnu-radio-and-building-my-own-am-receiver/)), which is the complex signal (blue in colour).

However, my version of the GRC has the FXFF block take in an additional "freq" input (grey in colour).

I have totally no idea what to feed into this new input and there is not much documentation out there.

Can anyone help?

Is this "freq" input some carrier wave at the baseband frequency?

If so, what block should I use to create this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`freq` is a message queue that allows you to change the center frequency of the filter. You should create a `pmt` pair containing `(intern("freq"), double(frequency)` where `frequency` is the new frequency in Hz. When the new frequency is applied the block will produce a new tag to inform downstream items where the frequency change was applied.

If you do not need to change the frequency during the execution of your flow-graph you can leave this port disconnected.

Comment: i can't run the flow-graph when it is unconnected. i have 2 followup questions:

1) which 'block' should i use in GRC to create this message queue?

2) lets say the baseband freq is 433Mhz, and the target frequency is 434Mhz, the 'new' frequency i should provide to this FXFF block is 434 Mhz?

Comment: That's weird. You should be able to run the flowgraph with the `freq` port disconnected. Which GNU Radio version you are using? For your second question. Practically speaking, your baseband signal is very difficult to have a frequency of  433 MHz. A baseband signal may be at the range of 0 -> samling_rate/2 Hz. If you use an SDR device (e.g USRP), that has a center frequency of 433 MHz, before it passes the samples to the flowgraph it down-converts them from the RF frequency to baseband. So if you want to filter 434 MHz your target frequency in baseband would be 1 MHz.

Comment: i reinstalled everything and it works unconnected now! thank you!